# JS dark/light theme function only applies to body, can't include other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I target other elements (besides body) in this function? Is it even possible to do this way?

So the function is allowing me to toggle dark/light theme using a button, works fine with body element but if I try to include any other element, the same way body is included it doesn't apply.

````
(function() {
    let onpageLoad = localStorage.getItem("tema") || "";
    let element = document.body;
    element.classList.add(onpageLoad);
    document.getElementById("tema").textContent =
      localStorage.getItem("tema") || "light";
})();
  
  function promeniTemu() {
    let element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("svetlaTema");
    let tema = localStorage.getItem("tema");
    if (tema && tema === "svetlaTema") {
      localStorage.setItem("tema", "");
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem("tema", "svetlaTema");
    }
  
    document.getElementById("tema").textContent = localStorage.getItem("tema");
  }```

querySelector seems to work, but if I use it for example on a header, the theme doesn't save on other pages, it refreshes, but if its only the body being changed theme works normally and saves everytime.
````

Comment: change **document.body** to **document.querySelector("#btn")** where #btn is the element you want to toggle the class

Comment: @imvain2 I was using the getElementById, now that I try querySelector it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: **getElementById** will work if the element has an ID and you pass it without the #. so for example if the element has **id="#btn"** you can use **getElementById("btn")**

Comment: I tried it that way but didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Using querySelector instead of getElementById works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).